# How to maintain Imageview scaletype?

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I am using a image view with a fixed height and width to display the the profile images. The image will some how bigger than the imageview, so i have used scale type fitXY and it suits into the image view exactly. But the problem is when the activity is resumed from onpause, that is like switching to some other activity and coming back to the same activity the scale type is changed. To overcome this am setting the image and scale type again in the onresume of the activity. But this doesn't looks good. Do you have any idea or have you experienced such problem like this. Ideas are most welcome. Thanks in adavance

Comment: explain where you have set scale type of the imageview, where have you been a0ded imageview like in xml, or activity,

Comment: @jeet Yes the image view is in XML and i am setting the image resource and scale type in java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Scale Type in xml and remove in activity

Answer (score 0):

To resize an ImageView you must do it after onResumed activity, so you can override the onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) method to write your code of scalling Image

```
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```